# What would cause a register loading change the value of another register?

Tags: assembly, gdb, arm64, armv8

I am moving a value into register `w5`

with this instruction `mov w5,0x64`

As I'm stepping through it in gdb I'm constantly checking the value in register `w10` which gets loaded beforehand.

After the above instruction `mov w5,0x64` somehow w10 also updates to a completely different value and I'm not sure how that is happening.

So what would cause a register loading change the value of another register if there is no instruction for that register (w10) that comes after this instruction to w5 register as above?

Comment: Is an interrupt happening there, like a page fault if the `mov w5, 0x64` is in a new page?  And your page-fault handler is broken and destroys `w10`?  Are you sure you debug info is correct?  Use GDB's `layout reg` to show disassembly, not source; maybe you're single-stepping a different instruction?  This isn't a [mcve], and `mov w5, immediate` doesn't change `w10` / `x10`.

Comment: @PeterCordes `mov w5, 0x64` does not access memory, how that could cause a page fault ?

Comment: @user3124812: My suggestion was  `mov w5, 0x64`  might be the first instruction in a new page, and code-fetch can page-fault.